# Is CVE-2023-24055 applicable to other password managers using the same format as the original KeePass?

Tags: password-management, cve, keepass

CVE-2023-24055 is a known vulnerability that enables an attacker to recover plaintext user credentials from the KeePass application.

However, due to the original KeePass being Windows-specific, I've been using a compatible "KeePass XC" for quite some time, and I'm sure there're other people that does the same.

So the question, is CVE-2023-24055 applicable to "KeePass XC" and other password managers using compatible password database formats?

Comment: This is mostly a non vulnerability. An attacker in position to perform this attack can perform much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears KeepassXC is not affected. From "Statement on CVE-2023-24055? #9041" https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/9041#issuecomment-1408260822

> *KeePassXC is not affected, because it doesn't support triggers.*

Taking a quick look through the main unlock routines [`DatabaseTabWidget::addDatabaseTab`](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/714c0a5be297345812299b371d18176551019c9f/src/gui/DatabaseTabWidget.cpp#L153) and [`DatabaseOpenWidget::openDatabase`](https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/blob/714c0a5be297345812299b371d18176551019c9f/src/gui/DatabaseOpenWidget.cpp#L238), and there's nothing that indicates some sort of scripted automation.